# Is it possible to set object equal null for stopping job in Spring Batch?

Tags: spring-batch

Following this [document](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/common-patterns.html#stoppingAJobManuallyForBusinessReasons), in order to stop job for some conditions, we could throw a RuntimeException:

```
public class PoisonPillItemProcessor<T> implements ItemProcessor<T, T> {

    @Override
    public T process(T item) throws Exception {
        if (isPoisonPill(item)) {
            throw new PoisonPillException("Poison pill detected: " + item);
        }
        return item;
    }
}
```

However, could I do like this:

```
public T process(T item) throws Exception {
    if (isPoisonPill(item)) {
        item = null;
    }
    return item;
}
```

I have tried and the result is that the ItemWriter will not insert the "isPoisonBill" item to database. But I would like to understand it more deeply about the safe or the performance of this solution. Is it accepted?

Comment: when you return `null` from the item processor, the item is filtered out and is not sent to the writer for writing. `I would like to understand it more deeply about the safe or the performance of this solution`: returning null and throwing an exception from the processor are both safe but are used for different use cases: one will filter out items and the other will stop the job. Both ways should not impact performance.

Answer (score 1):

We can do above to fail job manually and also we can do following to set the job exit with 1. Any case the job's chunk transaction will roll back and would not persist to database.

1. Autowire the JobExecutionContext

   @Value("#{stepExecution.jobExecution}")
   private JobExecution jobExecution;
2. Make sure the scope of the processor bean is defined as job.

   @Scope("job")
3. Set the exit status as FAILED.

   jobExecution.setExitStatus(ExitStatus.FAILED);

Comment: I means the "isPoisonBill" item won't be written into database by ItemWriter.

Comment: No it would not insert to database as the whole transaction in the chunk would fail.